# Loop through first item in foreach twice

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to loop through the first item in an array twice. My foreach looks like this:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $arr['item'];
}
```

The reason I'm asking is because I'm looping through and running a curl script that requires setting a cookie. On the first loop, it's not setting properly but it is on all others. Ideally I'd like to just hit that first twice, and overwrite the value I'm pulling.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to work around a problem instead of figuring out the issue with your first loop pass...

Comment: Correct, sir. And I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: To clarify, there are business reasons behind getting a piece of code running ASAP. This isn't production, I just need it working and don't have time to debug the curl code right now. I'll come back to that.

Comment: Why would you deliberately want to avoid a problem?  Anyhow, just put the first entry in twice using `array_unshift()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to make something twice with 1st element, you can make it this way

```
$firstItem = true;
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if ($firstItem) {
       $arr['item'];
       $arr['item'];
       $firstItem = false;
    } else {
       $arr['item'];
    }
}
```

But instead of making it twice, maybe you should find out why it doesn't work first time?
+1 to previous comment that you should fix a problem, but not workaround it.

Answer (score 1):

If order is not important:

```
  array_push($array, reset($array));
  foreach ($array as $arr) {
      ...
  }
```

If it is, better use Elena's suggestion.